# Looping interpolated SVG sprites

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend, string-interpolation

I've been trying to figure out how to interpolate these svg sprites in a loop. There's something missing to the html svg < use > element's path.

loop

```
each feature, slug in public.feature._data
  .feature__wrap
    .feature__image
      svg
        use(xlink:href="/assets/defs.svg#icon-feature-#")
  .feature__content
    h3.feature__title #{ feature.title }
    p.feature__text #{ feature.text }
```

svg sprites

```
<symbol id="icon-feature-1" viewBox='0 0 512 512'>
  <desc>Monitor Icon</desc>
  <path d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"/>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-feature-2" viewBox='0 0 512.004 512.004'>
  <desc>Cellphone Icon</desc>
  <path d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"/>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-feature-3" viewBox='0 0 64 64'>
  <desc>Gear Icon</desc>
  <path d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"/>
</symbol>
```

Note: I just used a random svg < path > to make it easier to read and lessen the amount of characters on the snippet

Note2: I've double checked the path of each single one and it works just fine so as to other sprites I have interpolated in other parts of my code which are not looping.

Comment: Which DSL are you using?

Comment: @Julia I'm using Jade / pug